# BST/GMT to UTC time

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016

Anyway to convert from BST datetime stored in DB to UTC

Had a look at  AT TIME ZONE but seems its from UTC to other times.

DB stores datetime as BST/GMT historically need to now return these as UTC

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime,GETDATE()) AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'
```

e.g

```
2019-07-08 12:01:55.060 ->  2019-07-08 11:01:550
```

Need to go back through loads of historic date 
data so could be GMT or BST depending on the time of the year and what year will determine cut over dates going back

Example below, i have the GMT/BST timezone times stored need them in UTC

```
DECLARE @dayLight TABLE(season VARCHAR(50), [gmt/bst] datetime, uct Datetime) 
INSERT INTO  @dayLight
VALUES('winter','2019-02-10 15:00:00','2019-02-10 15:00:00')
       ,('winter','2019-03-30 15:00:00','2019-03-30 15:00:00')
       ,('summer','2019-03-31 02:00:00','2019-03-31 01:00:00') --cut over
       ,('summer','2019-04-15 15:00:00','2019-03-30 14:00:00')
       ,('summer','2019-10-27 02:00:00','2019-10-27 01:00:00') --cut over
       ,('winter','2019-10-27 03:00:00','2019-10-27 03:00:00')

SELECT season,uct,[gmt/bst] FROM @dayLight
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Double up your `AT TIME ZONE` clauses to get what you want:

The first `AT TIME ZONE` clause specifies the current time zone you wish the value to be in, the second represents the time zone you wish to convert it to:

```
DECLARE @dayLight TABLE(season VARCHAR(50), [gmt/bst] datetime, utc Datetime) 
INSERT INTO  @dayLight
VALUES('winter','2019-02-10 15:00:00','2019-02-10 15:00:00')
       ,('winter','2019-03-30 15:00:00','2019-03-30 15:00:00')
       ,('summer','2019-03-31 02:00:00','2019-03-31 01:00:00') --cut over
       ,('summer','2019-04-15 15:00:00','2019-03-30 14:00:00')
       ,('summer','2019-10-27 01:59:59','2019-10-27 00:59:59') --cut over
       ,('winter','2019-10-27 03:00:00','2019-10-27 03:00:00')

SELECT season,utc,[gmt/bst]
        , [gmt/bst] AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS [gmt/bst -> utc]
        , [utc] AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AT TIME ZONE 'GMT Standard Time' AS [utc -> gmt/bst]
FROM @dayLight
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=dd41ff4528992c8efae6be627fd387e6)

**NOTE:** I updated the October cut over time going back to standard time to 1:59:59am from 2:00am as the 2:00am time marks the point BST returns to standard time from Daylight Saving Time, so at that point, Daylight Saving Time is no longer in effect (contrary to your example).

Comment: great so TIMEZONE 'GMT Standard Time' handles the BST shifts?

Comment: @davey, Per my testing it looks like it does.

Comment: Thats awesome i tried this originally but used  AT TIME ZONE 'Greenwich Standard Time'     AT TIME ZONE 'UTC'; GMT works though! thankyou!

Comment: It's "Daylight Saving Time" (or even "Daylight-saving Time", although that's arguably archaic).  We do not put daylight into a savings account and withdraw it months later.  We save daylight every day by getting out of bed an hour earlier.

Comment: @MontyHarder What?!?!  We can't accrue interest on that extra hour?  Thanks for the correction on what is [a common misuse here in the USA](https://www.timeanddate.com/time/dst/daylight-savings-time.html)!

Comment: How do you get the end resulting time though? So instead of 01:00:00 +01:00 it would just show 02:00:00?

Comment: @egmfrs `01:00:00 +01:00` means 1am with the timezone being represented as 1 hour ahead of UTC.  For instance, I live in the cetral part of the US, and at the time of this post it's `2023-11-02 13:28:21.930 -05:00`  AKA locally it's 1:28pm and my timezone is 5 hours behind UTC.  Hope that helps.

Comment: I understand that yes @JohnEisbrener - I don't think you understand my question. Ultimately I want to return the time as the user would expect it to be displayed.

Comment: @egmfrs Just cast it back to a DATETIME after you perform your time zone changes. 
 `SELECT CAST(GETDATE() AT TIME ZONE 'Central Standard Time' AT TIME ZONE 'UTC' AS DATETIME)` This will remove the offset and retain the time zone you converted to with the `AT TIME ZONE` statement.